# how to get last character of string in newline in UNIX

Tags: unix

Need to remove the last semicolon of all the strings present in a file and put it in the next line
in case it's the last character else ignore it

example:

```
input
This,is,a,test;
This,is,a,test;
This;is,a,test
This,is,a;test
This,is,a,test;

Output
This,is,a,test
;
This,is,a,test
;
This;is,a,test
This,is,a;test
This,is,a,test
;
```

Comment: Are you editing in vim or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, i am using Vi Editor and Shell Script, need to replace all the character into a new line in a file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat x.txt 
This,is,a,test;
This,is,a,test;
This;is,a,test
This,is,a;test
This,is,a,test;
```

```
$ sed 's/;$/\n;/' x.txt 
This,is,a,test
;
This,is,a,test
;
This;is,a,test
This,is,a;test
This,is,a,test
;
```

`sed 's/r/x/'` replaces the regex `r` with the string `x`.

`;$` is a regex which matches `;` at the end of a line.

`\n;` is just a newline followed by `;`.

So it's basically prefixes the last `;` of each line with a newline.